# Pushing a div inside a div to the very bottom that works with IE7

Tags: html, css

I'm running in to a slight problem where I am not able to align and get the same effect I get from chrome in IE7. What I am trying to accomplish is to push a div with a background to the bottom of a container div.

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mn34r/

Code

```
<div class="container">
  <img style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px" src="img/img.png">
  <div class="description"><br>
  <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">Harry's Nose</span><br>

  <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="button"><i style="color:#fff;
  </i>Read More</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
    border:solid 1px #e2e2e2;
    height:327px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}

.description{
    height:110px;
    background-color:#F1F1F1;
    text-align:center;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In IE7  `top:` overwrites `bottom:`, so you need to use an IE6/7 hack with CSS expressions.

```
#forceBottom {
  position:absolute;
  top:expression(
     document.documentElement.scrollTop +  
     document.documentElement.clientHeight - 
     this.clientHeight
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Diodeus I tried implementing your solution with no luck. Could you please edit the fiddle provide as a working demo for me to check? Thank you for taking your time to help me with this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have IE7 to try it with.